# Reference error while trying to run an angular application on edge

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-edge, stomp

I have an angular application where I send notifications to the UI suing web sockets. I use stomp for that.
This works fine on chrome but on edge I receive the following error when notifications are sent from the backend-

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: 'TextEncoder' is not defined
ReferenceError: 'TextEncoder' is not defined
```

I found that the error was due to stomp. Stomp uses text encoder/decoder which is not supported by Microsoft browser from 2018. Adding the following resolves the issue-

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding.min.js"></script>
```

However I need to do this through polyfill. I don't know how to do that. Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally Edge is a not a well-recomended browser and lot of Angular features don't properly work in Edge. Also some CSS properties as well. whch version of Angular are you using

Comment: I'm using angular 7

Comment: can you put your sample code where this error is occured

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? With only the above error message, we can't tell why the issue occurs. Please provide [a minimal smaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676056/why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-textencoder-is-undefined-in-ie11-after-impo